# Changing Window Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a small application to remind me of up coming events. It normally sits in the bottom right corner of the screen and cannot be resized or moved. I want a menu item to allow the user to resize and move the window. I am able to do the resizing by using the statement:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
```

I cannot get it to move. In the MainWindow function I set the Window Style to None:

```
this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
```

In the Move method, triggered from the menu, I set the Window style to Single border:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Style = System.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
```

However, when this instruction is processed the window style stays as None.

How can I change the Window style dynamically?

Comment: As I see, you already have the answer. But I can give a little advice: look toward to tray icon application. Perhaps such a solution will be better and more convenient)

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Style = System.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
```

This line should have given you a compilation error, since you are trying to assign two different types, and should have set instead:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle = System.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
```